# Как из объекта со вложенными объектами сделать один одоноуровневый?

Tags: javascript

Как преобразовать данный объект:

```
{
  "Me": 11,
  "Children": {
    "Mike": {
      "Tom": 12
    },
    "Sister": {
      "Mary": 15
    }
  }
}
```

в плоский объект:

```
{
    "Me" : 11,
    "ChildrenMikeTom" : 12,
    "ChildrenSisterMary" : 15
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пробегаете по полям объекта при помощи цикла `for in`, определяете тип поля при помощи `typeof` и если тип `object`, то запускаете поиск рекурсивно

```js
var obj = {
  "Me": 11,
  "Children": {
    "Mike": {
      "Tom": 12
    },
    "Sister": {
      "Mary": 15
    }
  }
};

function merge(AObj, APrfx) {
  var res = [];
  for (var i in AObj) {
    if (typeof AObj[i] === 'object')
      res = res.concat(merge(AObj[i], APrfx + i));
    else
      res.push({name: APrfx + i, val: AObj[i]});
  }
  return res;
}

var arr = merge(obj, '');
var res = {};
for (var i in arr) {
  res[arr[i].name] = arr[i].val;
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за доступное объяснение!